# In $f(t) = \cos(\omega \cdot \log t)$, would I refer to $\omega$ as a frequency, does it have another name, or does it lack a common name?

Tags: terminology

If I have the function $f(t)=\cos(\omega \cdot t)$, $\omega$ is commonly referred to as a frequency.

Suppose instead, though, I have the function $f(t) = \cos(\omega \cdot \log t)$.  Would I still refer to $\omega$ as a frequency?

And for that matter, is there any special name for this more general type of cosine-of-log generally?

Comment: I would, because you can use change of variables to bring expression $f(t) = \cos\left(\omega\!\cdot\!\log t\right)$ to the original form $f(t) = \cos\left(\omega\!\cdot\!t\right)$ bia change of variables

Comment: I wouldn't. I might call it the log frequency or something?